# Cordova-Ionic-VS error : meta data "%fullpath" cannot be applied

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-cordova

I am getting this error when I try to open an Ionic project in Visual Studio 2015:

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

From the error log, you are putting the project into `Cordova-Ionic-projects` folder, which is not a valid path for `cordova-plugin-splashscreen`.

To fix the problem, please move your project to other folder.